# Why are derived quantities always expressed as a product or division of base quantities?

Tags: classical-mechanics, dimensional-analysis, units

I have seen many equations that relate derived quantities with base quantities as a product of those quantities or division of them, e.g., $F=ma$, $V=\frac{S}{t}$, etc, but I want the feel of this concept. Please help!

Comment: Is not that just the definition of a derived quantity? You can freely choose (almost) any three quantities as the base quantities, e.g. speed, acceleration, and angular momentum, and express all other quantities in classical mechanics as derived quantities of these.

Comment: A side note: whether derived quantities make sense or not, the units must match for all elements of an equation, on both sides of the equal sign, or the equation is dimensionally inconsistent (aka, wrong).  Thus, consideration of units is a useful and valuable tool to find and correct errors.

Answer (score 1):

We can give an elegant reason why you're (almost) right. The requirement for [dimensional homogeneity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Dimensional_homogeneity) constrains what functions of dimensionful variables are legal. However, arbitrary functions of dimensionless ones are fine. [That's how you end up with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation#Derivation) relationships like$$f_b\left(\frac{F_{\operatorname{d}}}{\tfrac12\rho Au^2},\,\frac{u\sqrt{A}}{\nu}\right)=0,$$an [implicit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function) relating a drag force to other variables. In particular, the comma-separated fractions are both dimensionless. The result $f_b=0$ amounts to$$F_d=\tfrac12\rho Au^2g\left(\frac{u\sqrt{A}}{\nu}\right),$$where the function $g$ is so underdetermined the result isn't simply "a product or division of base quantities".